# Error QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running

Tags: scripting, qt, texstudio

**Edit:** *I discovered that the problem is not related with the script cited below, but I'll leave it there just for history.*

Well, this error appears when I close texstudio **with the viewer open** (xdvi or evince). If I close the viewer first and then close texstudio, no problem, no errors on the terminal.

This is the error:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
```

---

**Old text:** Every time when I close my texstudio after opened by my script below I got this error on the terminal:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
```

Here is the script `fastex.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyleft 2012 by Sigur

caminho=/home/$USER
file=$caminho/fastex-temp
exec 3>&1
exec > "$file".tex
printf '\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsart}\n' 
printf '\\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}\n' 
printf '\\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}\n' 
printf '\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n' 
printf '\usepackage{tikz}\n'
printf '\usepackage[brazil]{babel}\n'
printf '\n' 
printf '\\begin{document}\n' 
printf '\n'
printf '\\end{document}' 

linha=$(wc -l < "$file".tex)
texstudio --line $linha  "$file".tex
find . -name  "fastex-temp.*" | grep -vP '.tex$|.pdf$' | while read -r i; do rm $i; done
```

I guess that the problem is with the `find` command to delete auxiliary files. So, is `find` executed only after I close texstudio?

Thanks for a while. Best wishes.

**Edit**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your script, with latest (2.4) version there was no problem,

If you forget to terminate the QProcess before closing main window of your program, you usually get this warning, I think the author has fixed that problem:

`QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.`

texstudio doesn't release the pesudo tty when it's started, so deleting of files only start after texstudio quits.

And to remove files, it could be saved to one line:

`find . -name "fastex-temp.*[^(tex|pdf)]" -exec rm {} \;`

**EDIT**

To test if the above command works fine, copy and run the following script:

```
DIR=$(mktemp -d) 
cd ${DIR}
touch fastex-temp.{aa,tex,pdf,bb}
find . -name "fastex-temp.*[^(tex|pdf)]" -exec rm {} \;
```

Now execute the command above and you would see only *.tex and *.pdf is left here.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. For you, no error. OK. But your suggestion is to update my texstudio? Second: your command `find` will delete and keep only the pdf and tex files? I wish this. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur yes; and i provide a test case in my updated answer

Comment: I tried with 4 files `.{aux,.log,.tex,.pdf}` but only `.log` was deleted. Strange. Well, do you think that the problem with my version of texstudio could be fixed if I change my last line, maybe removing the auxiliaries files by other way? How did you install this new version of texstudio?

Comment: @Sigur what shell, and distro do you use ? I provided a screenshot, that command works for me

Comment: Hum, I don't know. I think that it is bash. I am using Lubuntu 11.10. I will edit my post and put a print screen.

Comment: Dear warl0ck, sorry. I don't want to take your time. I appreciate your help. I've tested again now my script and no errors appear. I really don't know why. I'll close the question. Thanks. ps: your command still does not delete `.aux` files.

Comment: @Sigur - Try with -regex instead of -name

Comment: @jordanm, with `-regex` option, none was deleted.

Comment: @Sigur did you copy-paste all the code above for testing ?

Comment: Here is: thiago@vaio:/tmp/tmp.GqzyW4Zutj$ touch fastex-temp.{aa,tex,pdf,bb,aux}
thiago@vaio:/tmp/tmp.GqzyW4Zutj$ ls
fastex-temp.aa   fastex-temp.bb   fastex-temp.tex
fastex-temp.aux  fastex-temp.pdf
thiago@vaio:/tmp/tmp.GqzyW4Zutj$ find . -name "fastex-temp.*[^(tex|pdf)]" -exec rm {} \;
thiago@vaio:/tmp/tmp.GqzyW4Zutj$ ls
fastex-temp.aux  fastex-temp.pdf  fastex-temp.tex
thiago@vaio:/tmp/tmp.GqzyW4Zutj$  Note that I add an aux file and it was not delete.